# Receive Authorization header on anonymous url using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, http-headers, authorization

How can an `Authorization` header be accessed on anonymous urls?

My security configuration looks like:

```
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/legacy-login").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/things/*").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
```

Authentication in general works fine. However, on `/legacy-login` I need to do some migration and need to access the authorization header without spring boot managing the authorization.  Although `/legacy-login` is marked anonymous as soon as there are requests, spring intercepts the request and tries to authorize itself (what then results into 401).

How can I make Spring let the auth header through on that single url?

Comment: Try `.antMatchers("/login").anonymous().antMatchers("/legacy-login").permitAll()`.

Comment: Sadly this did not work, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I foudn one solution myself. Instead of fiddleing around with `.anonymous()` and `.permitAll()` I added `/legacy-login` as ignore rule:

```
    override fun configure(web: WebSecurity) {
        super.configure(web)
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/legacy-login")
    }
```

Comment: For anyone wondering why this works - Spring Security Filter Chain is skipped for all urls in web.ignoring()